# How to create a local and remote Stateless Session Bean interface?

Tags: jakarta-ee, intellij-idea

I'm trying to get a grip of IntelliJ Idea and how it works. I need to create a Session bean ejb 3.x as you do in Eclipse but in IntelliJ Idea it seems to be a little bit difficult.

This is how I try to do.

First I right click at the project/new/Stateless Session Bean.
Then I get this popup window:

[image]

I type in ejb-name and then press OK.

Now I don't know where to go to create a local and a remote session bean. 
Should I press the button "Change EJB Classes"? Because when I do it this popup shows up.

[image]

Am I suppose to mark off the Remote Interface and Local Interface boxes?
And whats the difference between Local Home and Local? Because when I do this I get two Interfaces for each type(Local and Home).

Comment: might help to go thru a ejb 3.x tutorial and look at the meaning of local, local home, the xmls that deploy them in to jboss or other app container ... can do a small example with just textpad/ notepad++

Comment: You create a JavaEE6 Application?

Comment: @Patrick it's a Java EE7 Application.

Comment: sorry, can you tell me how to open this Change EJB Classes dialog? if i create a EJB from the EJB Facet i only got the first create EJB dialog, but there isn't any option to create a remote or local interface.. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, `EJB 2.1 or earlier client view`  needed the existence of a home and component interface. In JEE7 (`EJB 3.x API`) this is optional.

If you create a `Local` or `Remote` Interface, it depends on your decicion, for example if your SessionBean proceeds the orders of your customers and works together with the billing bean, it would be a good candidate for `Local Access`.

If your Bean will be accessed from other clients, outside of your e.g. `Glassfish`, then you should enable remote access.

By default Interfaces with no annotation in JEE7 are `@Local`

The Local Client

- runs on the same virtual machine
- it could be a Session Bean or another Web Component

**Local Client:**

```
@Local
public interface OrderServiceLocal {
   // ...
}


@Local(OrderServiceLocal.class)
@Stateless
public class OrderService implement OrderServiceLocal {
   // ...
}
```

And in your CDI Bean you can use your OrderService like this:

```
@Named(name = "MyCDIBean")
@SessionScoped
public class MyCDIBean {

   // ...

   // your applicationserver creates an instance of 
   // the Service if it is needed
   // and he also handles the lifecycle
   @Inject
   OrderServiceLocal orderService;

   // ...

   public List<Orders> listOrders() {
      return orderService.listOrders();
   }

}
```

**Remote Clients**

- the Remote Client can run in a different JVM or / and on a different machine
- the Bean which should be accessed must implement the remote interface, because the Remote Client can not access through a Non-Interface View

Remote Interface

```
@Remote
public interface OrderServiceRemote {

   // methods

}

@Remote(OrderServiceRemote.class)
@Stateless
public class OrderService implement OrderServiceRemote {

   // do something cool in here ;)

}



@Named(name = "MyCDIBean")
@SessionScoped
public class MyCDIBean {

  // ...

  // your applicationserver creates an instance of 
  // the Service if it is needed
  // and he also handles the lifecycle
  @Inject
  OrderServiceLocal orderService;

  // ...

  public List<Orders> listOrders() {
    return orderService.listOrders();
  }

}
```

Both Interfaces define `Business` and `Lifecycle` methods which are specific for the Bean.

Different is also the JNDI Lookup for `Local` or `Remote` Views, for example if you write your own client and use the InitialContext.lookup() to get access.

**@Local**

```
OrderServiceLocal osl = (OrderServiceLocal)
         InitialContext.lookup("java:module/OrderServiceLocal");
```

**@Remote**

```
OrderServiceRemote osr = (OrderServiceRemote)
        InitialContext.lookup("java:global/myApp/OrderServiceRemote");
```

So,i hope this will help you a bit, i needed to write it as an answer, because the text and listing would be to long for a comment.

Patrick

Comment: How could I import the class OrderServiceLocal or OrderServiceRemote in a different project? Should I copy the interfaces in the project where I'll make the lookup?